# automatically generate outlook signatures from templates

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Target: Generate the e-mail signatures for the users so they can be as little creative with it as possible.

We are using Microsoft exchange and for email/calendar we are using Microsoft Outlooks - Ol'good Desktop client and WebApp and Aondroid and iOS Apps.

I can locate the signatures desktop client uses. So I can build templates (our mothertongue and EN versions), edit them and copy them so user can use it. I can do it using a script, so it is a blackbox thingy for the user.

Where the other incarnations of Outlook store the signature files and how can I work with them outside the apps? How can I deliver the signatures with as little differencies as possible with as fewer actions of the user as possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Exchange account, we can use [Set-MailboxMessageConfiguration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/client-access/set-mailboxmessageconfiguration?view=exchange-ps) cmdlet to configure the signature settings of Outlook on the web that are applied to specific mailboxes.

Got the idea from this thread: [OWA 2013 uniform signature](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d9b7bba3-ba4f-43b1-a0f7-4a8796623d61/owa-2013-uniform-signature?forum=exchangesvrgeneral)